# Running PMD from Java project

Tags: pmd

I want to run the PMD tool from my Java project. I've already imported all the jars to my project and have access to all the methods:

[image: PMD suggestions]

But I don't know how to use it. I can't find any example or documentation anywhere.

I know how to run it through the terminal though.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was pretty easy after all. For example:

```
String[] arguments = { "-d", src_folder, "-f", output_format, "-R", rulesets, "-r", output_file };
PMD.run(arguments);
```

The variables are Strings. Just like on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use PMD is [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Pmd.html):

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'
```

or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/usage.html):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Just remember about configuration, as defaults are usually not enough.

If you really need to invoke PMD programmatically from Java, just follow the approach used in [maven-pmd-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-pmd-plugin-3.5/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/pmd/).

Another easy way is to invoke `net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask` ANT task.